# How to prove that $T-2I$ is an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a difficulty with the following assignment, and I would be grateful if some one could help me. Given:

$$T: \mathbb R^3 \to\mathbb R^3,\quad  T(1,2,3)=(-2,-4,-6),\quad  \dim \operatorname{Im} T <\dim\ker T$$

I need to prove: $T-2I$ is an isomorphism

I just don't get the last part about the relation of the isomorphism to the eigenvalues, please can some one explain in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) $\;T\neq 0\;$ , and thus

2) $\;\dim\text{Im}\,T=1\;,\;\;\dim\ker T=2$

3) $\;T\;$ cannot have more than one non-zero eigenvalue

4) One of the eigenvalues of $\;T\;$ is $\;-2\;$

5) For any $\;\lambda\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;T-\lambda I\;$ is an isomorphis iff $\;\lambda\;$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $\;T\;$

Comment: why T cannot have more than one non-zero eigenvalue?

Comment: There'd be two non-zero eigenvectors, one for each eigenvalue, but then these eigenvectors would be linearly independent (why?), and thus $\;\dim\text{Im}\,T\ge 2\;$ ...

Comment: Can you please explain number 5 i did not understand the conclusion. I know that in order fot a transformation to be isomorfic it needs to be a projection transformation and dimImT needs to be = dimW (or dimV in this case) how does this connect to the last assumption?